# error 500 in combination with PHP Fatal error: Cannot redeclare GetText function.php

Tags: php, function, gettext

i have the next error in my php error log : `PHP Fatal error:  Cannot redeclare GetText() in /usr/local/www/apache22/data/sv3/is/include/function.php on line 211`

The function looks like this:

```
 function GetText($id) {
$query = mysql_query("SELECT `desc` FROM `account`.`is_desc` WHERE `id` = $id LIMIT 1;");
$sql = mysql_fetch_array($query);
if(empty($sql[0])) {
    $sql[0] = "Descriere indisponibila";
}
return $sql[0];
}
```

The return in browser is Error 500!

Comment: You have GetText() declared elsewhere.  Find it and remove it, or rename your second function.

Answer (score 5):

functions in php aren't case-sensitive

You've likely collided with a built-in localization function [`gettext()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.gettext.php). Even if this isn't the case your function should be renamed for portability's sake.

Answer (score 0):

There are two possibilities:

1. You have declared this function earlier somewhere else
2. You have included the file that contains function declaration twice.

Answer (score 0):

PHP does not support function overloading, nor is it possible to undefine or redefine previously-declared functions.

You have include two function with the same name `GetText()` in the same page script, can be via include or another way.

As @SenorAmor says Find it and remove it, or rename your second function.

[Manual](http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php)